# Symfony on Heroku: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I've successfully deployed my Symfony 2 App to Heroku but now, when I'm trying to access it, I receive the following 403 error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

This is the log from Heroku:

```
2015-07-29T14:31:41.827491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=557a70f4-ea11-4519-b8df-301b714f6ffa fwd="151.77.103.253" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=387
2015-07-29T14:31:41.828428+00:00 app[web.1]: [Wed Jul 29 14:31:41.827438 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 104:tid 140466989270784] [client 10.100.0.139:16096] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2015-07-29T14:31:41.829009+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.100.0.139 - - [29/Jul/2015:14:31:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
```

It seems that Symfony (or Heroku?) is trying to serve the directory `/app/` but I think this is not correct, as from the logs:

> 2015-07-29T14:31:41.828428+00:00 app[web.1]: [Wed Jul 29
>   14:31:41.827438 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 104:tid 140466989270784]
>   [client 10.100.0.139:16096] AH01276: **Cannot serve directory /app/**: No
>   matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and
>   server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Following the [tutorial on the Symfony Documentation about how to deploy to Heroku](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/heroku.html), I've created my `.procfile` and into I've put:

```
web: bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

I've also removed the `DemoBundle`, and now my root URL is configured in the `DefaultController` in this way:

```
<?php

// \AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="Homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I think, in the end, there are some problems with my `.htaccess`, that is the one shipped with Symfony Standard Edition:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Another part of my App could be the cause of this issue: `security.yml`, that currently is this:

```
# you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html#bootstrapping
acl:
    connection: default

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    # ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:    true
        anonymous: true

    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But, accessing `http:// my-app.herokuapp.com/login` (that seems to be "open to the world"), I receive anyway a beautiful 404 error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

**So, which could be the problem? Which setting is preventing me from accessing my Symfony App on Heroku?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not possible. more than 3 hours to find a solution.
A solution that could not be found in all the code I posted here.

A really, simple, stupid, small solution: the `procfile` name.
Are you noticing? I'm writing it all in lowercase letters.

The solution? `Procfile`, with the first letter in uppercase.

It was an hell, but finally I have my app up and running! :D

Comment: so I am at the same spot going crazy as it been over 11 hours now that i am trying to find the solution to this, my Profile name is correct but still i am getting the same error. I will really appreciate if you can let me know if i am missing something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150864/symfony-deployment-on-heroku-points-to-app-folder

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to type that line without quotation mark.

For Example

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone still having this problem you can try to replace the double quotes with single quotes in the Procfile

Example

```
"web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/"
```

Should be

```
'web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for this notice when deploying:
NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: heroku-php-apache2'.
For me, there was no difference after I wrote web: heroku-php-apache2 public/ directly in Heroku cloud settings.
Then I found this [solution](https://insidert.medium.com/fix-no-procfile-using-web-heroku-php-apache2-for-laravel-on-windows-d0aeeb725784) and it works.

> If you are not on the local master branch while deploying the code to
> Heroku, you will end up with errors. You need to push to Heroku
> master while you are on your local master branch. This is the default
> setup.

In other words, new docroot can be set only from Procfile and deployment should be pushed from local **master** branch.

Comment: Please answer the question here too because sometimes sites go offline or links die and a visitor will not be able to do much with a dead link