# Symfony deployment on heroku points to app folder

Tags: php, heroku, symfony, procfile

I am trying to deploy the symfony app on heroku and I am able to update the schema and all perfectly fine however when i try to access the site I get

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

So using the command `heroku logs --num 10` i can see the error

> Cannot serve directory /app/web/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory
>   index forbidden by Options directive

As you can see heroku is trying to access `/app/web/` rather than just `web`, because of this even my assets are being access via `app/web/css` which is ofcourse wrong.

So how can i get rid of this `app`? I do not understand why Heroku is even pointing at that.

I have gone through the steps mentioned in [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/heroku.html) over and over and I cant seem to find out what I am missing?

The Procfile seems to be point to web so where is this `app` coming from?

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

I have gone through other articles online like the one as following but nothing seems to be fixing my problem.

[Symfony on Heroku: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704032/symfony-on-heroku-403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Heroku you need to create the `.Procfile` and upload that **or** create the `app.json` [Schema file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) and then based on that Heroku will create the `.Procfile` for you automatically, [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/app.json) you can see the `app.json` example for Symfony app.

Another thing that needs to be crossed checked is make sure in your public directory the `.htaccess` file was also uploaded. In Symfony the public directory is the `web` folder and in my case the `.htaccess` file was missing.

After making sure of the above two steps my app works perfectly fine on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/web/` instead of `web/`: add the leading slash!

Your `Procfile` file should contain this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /web/
```

Note the leading `/` in the path to the `web` folder!

Comment: Thanks @Aerendir unfortunately that did not help :) I did end up fixing it by adding 'app.json' in the root https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema I will add the answer in a while. I do very much appreciate you having a look.